# Wobbly text on transform scale

Tags: html, css

When I try to scale a div on mouse hover, the text wobbles/jitters and the animation is not smooth. This is especially apparent in FireFox, but can also be seen in Chrome.

Are there any changes I can do to make the animation smooth?

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jL4dbxf9/

```css
.mtw { 
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
.mt .mp {
  text-align: center;
}
.mt .mp .ma {
  color: #fff;
  font: 800 40px OpenSansBold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.mt .header-blue {
  background: blue;
}
.mt {
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
}
.mt:hover{
  z-index: 1; 
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

```html
<div class="mtw">
  <div class="mt">
    <div class="header-blue">
      <h2 class="mp">
        <span class="ma">49</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So you've got multiple things going on here, and unfortunately it's going to require various things between browsers as you tackle some of the nuances of the measure / arrange passes, anti-aliasing, hardware acceleration, perspective, etc...

```css
.mtw {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin:0 auto; 
}
.mt .mp { text-align: center }
.mt .mp .ma {
  color: #fff;
  font: 800 40px OpenSansBold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 60px;
}
.mp { margin: 0 }
.mt .header-blue {
  background: blue;
}
.mt {
  transition: all 0.4s linear;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
.mt:hover {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
       -o-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
          transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
}

/* --- cleaner way --- */
#boom {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  font: 800 40px OpenSansBold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.4s linear;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  will-change: transform;  
}
#boom:hover { 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
       -o-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
          transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px);
}

/* --- Another way --- */
#weee {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
  font: 800 40px OpenSansBold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  min-height: 60px;
  max-width:200px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transition: font-size 0.4s linear;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  will-change: font-size;
}
#weee:hover {
  font-size: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mtw">
  <div class="mt">
    <div class="header-blue">
      <h2 class="mp">
        <span class="ma">49</span>
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br/><br/>

Or, cleaner way....
<div id="boom">50</div>

<br/><br/>

Or, an entirely different way...
<div id="weee">51</div>
```

So if we look through the changes, we see some things added...

`backface-visibility: hidden;` = The user doesn't care about the back, remove it from the compositor consideration...

`-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;` = I'm sure the font is cool, but you re-try redrawing all the pixel specific shading crap on the fly smoothly....

`translate3d( 0, 0, 0)` = 'ol hack to force hardware acceleration in some instances and let the gpu help out.

`margin: 0` = on your h2 to remove the user agent margin garbage from consideration...

`perspective(1px)` = Because you're transforming, remind it where home is...

Between these hopefully you should see the result you're expecting, hope it helps, cheers!

Oh, and just a quick PS: You don't need that many elements to accomplish the same thing (unless there's more to your example than what we see), I would try to shake that habit. One element and some text could deliver the same result with a cleaner DOM and less for the compositor thread to care about while doing its thing.

ADDENDUM; Eventually with `scale` you're going to run into a resolution loss as it's resizing an elements dimensions and its children on a 2d plane with a rasterization. Avoiding blurry effect the larger something is scaled is inevitable (as far as I know today) unless you want refactor into say a canvas with zoom, or easier yet treat the instance for what it is and instead just target the font in this scenario since it's the only thing actually needing to stay legible. So see the added example, which is targeting font-size as a vector instead. Cheers!

Comment: thank you for your help. The jiggling text on Chrome is fixed but now the text is a bit blurry. Its hard to see in this simple sample, but you can see the blurriness by comparing screenshots of the 49 in your answer to the 49 in the original question. Also, on Firefox, it still jiggles with your provided solution, but it doesn't get blurry. Any tips to fix these extra issues?

Comment: @jjdem see updated answer, hopefully we can find you a compromise. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! All I had to add was `transform: scale(1.1) translate3d( 0, 0, 0) perspective(1px)` to stop the jiggling.

Comment: @agconti right on, the `scale(1.1)` probably isn't necessary on what you're trying and anytime you change the scale it can lose resolution, that was just in the OP's original question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When animating a modal the text was jumping and this solved my issue:

```
.modal > * {
  transform: scale(1.000001);
}
```

Which don't seems to modify dimensions too much, and worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple things are happening. But this should fix it:

```
.mt {
  transition: transform 0.4s linear;
  transform: scale(.9);
}

.mt:hover{
    z-index: 1; 
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);    
}
```

1. It is difficult to scale text. The reason I believe you are seeing it jump is that the text is recalculating line height and letter spacing during your animation.
2. The more important problem that I saw was that you set scale to over 1. Scale should start small and end at 1 as the biggest. You can see scale jank when you scale a picture over 1 really clearly.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Changing the scale makes for a smooth animation when going from 0.9 to 1 scale, however when the mouse is unhovered and it goes back to 0.9 scale from 1 scale, the animation is not smooth and it still wobbles. Again, this is most apparent in FireFox: https://jsfiddle.net/fy6nvqw0/