# CSS scale on iFrame content makes fonts and images appear crispy

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with scaling down content in iFrames. When applying CSS transform:scale on an iframe, the content appears crispy. (not antialiasing text and images)

Here is a codepen I created as example:

```
<iframe id="desktop" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design" scrolling="no"></iframe>

iframe {
    width: 1600px;
    height: 992px;
    transform: scale(0.4181);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.3181);
    -o-transform: scale(0.3181);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.3181);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.3181);
    transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    -o-transform-origin: top left;
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    -moz-transform-origin: top left;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

https://codepen.io/front-end-developer/pen/gEPvKv

Applying transform(scale) on an iframe, the content in the iframe is not antialiased. Is there another CSS solution to scale down iframe content with antialiasing enabled?

Here is the full demo to create a [responsive mockup](https://www.createmockup.com/generate/)

Comment: Yeah, that's what happens when you use `scale`.

Comment: What you stated is obvious. What's not obvious is what is your question. Please make sure you read (and apply) [ask].

Comment: Most likely, applying a blur filter will improve the overall visual quality of the displayed content, up to a point. You need to play around with its radius and see what works best for each case. Another option (typically used) is to take snapshots and use professional image processing tools for reduction.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I previously used CSS (scale) on images without a problem. But applying CSS on iframes makes the content appear not antialiased. Applying blur effect makes it even more fuzzy

Comment: iframe + scale + transform-origin = not actually responsive DOM design and will continue to be a thorn in your side. This is a really broad one to try and tackle given the current structure/strategy.

Comment: @ChrisW. It's not about responsive DOM. What I'm trying to say here is that applying transform(scale) on an iframe, the content in the iframe is not antialiased, why not?

Comment: Well there's a number of technical reasons. You could start by trying some [common tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708013/wobbly-text-on-transform-scale/52768926#52768926) though and see if you can get a better result. However scaling something like an entire `iframe` and its contents in one pass is something I would never expect to retain an optimal result.